# Is LAST_INSERT_ID() in a transaction dependable?

Tags: .net, mysql, ado.net, concurrency, thread-safety

I am using mysql/ado.net/C# heres my problem
I know mysql is concurrent, however i have file data (the thumbname name) and db data (the row) to be in sync.

If i start a transaction and it fails for any reason will this be a problem? If i have this code ran at the same time on two cores will they clobber eachother? I essentially need to know if 1) the last_insert_id is dependable on not changing. 2) if one transaction uses said rowid that another transaction wont use it.

```
start transaction
insert statement, however i dont want it to be active yet;
select LAST_INSERT_ID()
File.Delete(lastid)//may exist from a transaction that failed
File.Move(thumbImage, lastid)
transaction.commit()//ok done
```

Is this safe? Why or why not?

Comment: You do realize that your file system has no notion of a transaction and that for this reason rolling back the transaction will *not* undo the changes in the file system, don't you? From what I see, while an exception in File.Delete or File.Move will cause the transaction to roll back, an exception in File.Move will *not* undo File.Delete.

Comment: @veggen: i dont need the file i am deleting at all. In fact i said it may not exist and that it has failed if it does exist. I dont remember if thumbImage is generated or is the original but i think i check to see if it exist and if it does i know it is 'completed' and remove the job transaction (and if i screwed up somehow then it will still remove which is ok cause it would be an unrecoverable mistake but this job queue hasnt failed and looks solid to me)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

MySQL's last_insert_id() is dependable in that it's always the LAST insert performed by THAT PARTICULAR connection. It won't report an insert id created by some other connection, it won't report an insert that you did two connections ago. It won't matter which cpu core the actual insert occured on, and which core the last_insert_id() call is processed on. It will always be the right ID number for that connection.

If you roll back a transaction that did an insert, last_insert_id() will STILL report that new id, even though it no longer exists. The id will not be reused, however, in a subsequent insert

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know "LAST insert performed by THAT PARTICULAR connection".

Comment: clearly took away all my curiousity and worries to this useful function

Comment: If I'm inserting while in a stored proc, is this function guaranteed to give me the id that I just inserted in that proc. I assume since its an atomic transaction the answer would be yes, but need confirmation.

Comment: Docs for [the function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). You don't need lock or transaction for it!